# C - fields in struct used between threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, struct

I start a thread and pass to its entry point a struct which has had some values initialized. The pointer I get is correct, and I can get the pointer to a particular field in that struct, but the value I see there is not what I originally set it to be. How does that happen?

Example:

```
typedef int (*CNX_Algorithm)(void*, int);

typedef struct
{
    CNX_Algorithm algorithm;
    thrd_t thread;
    void *data;
    int go;
} CNX_Instance;

int RunContinuously(void *instance)
{
    int count = 0;
    int *go = &((CNX_Instance*)instance)->go;
    CNX_Algorithm algorithm = ((CNX_Instance*)instance)->algorithm;
    void *data = ((CNX_Instance*)instance)->data;
    printf("new thread: %p %p %p\n", instance, &((CNX_Instance*)instance)->data, data);
    while(*go) count += algorithm(data, 1);
    return count;
}

CNX_Instance *CNX_StartInstance(CNX_Algorithm algorithm, void *data)
{
    CNX_Instance *instance = malloc(sizeof(CNX_Algorithm));
    instance->algorithm = algorithm;
    instance->data = data;
    printf("original thread: %p %p %p\n", instance, &instance->data, instance->data);
    instance->go = 1;
    thrd_create(&instance->thread, RunContinuously, instance);
    return instance;
}
```

Output:

```
original thread: 024b1f78 024b1f84 0019ff10
new thread: 024b1f78 024b1f84 80000008
```

Huh???

EDIT:

I should mention that if I CALL RunContinuously instead of starting a thread there it works as expected. Go figure.

Comment: You probably have a data race on `go`, which is not atomic, and you are checking its value in a loop that does not seem to modify it, without synchronization. If you are asynchronously modifying it in a different thread, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Downvoters: fair, fair, but please don't be too harsh I am tired :(

Comment: EOF: agreed - it happens to work for me but I plan to fix it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one issue I see is that you're mallocing the size of a CNX_Algorithm instead of a CNX_Instance. The first is four bytes while the second is probably 16 or more (on 32-bit systems). It could be memory corruption if 4 byte allocations come from a different bucket than, say, 16 byte allocations.

Comment: I'll accept as answer when it allows me. Yes, this solved the issue. Stupid stupid stupid bug.

Comment: Awesome. :) you're probably reading heap block metadata in the new thread, or something from an adjacent allocation. Glad it helped!